# How can I open a web assembly from my hard drive without using localhost?

Tags: blazor, webassembly

I have a web assembly under file:///C:/dotnet.wasm and cannot open it via chrome.

Also opening a html file like this in the same folder does not work although the dlls and the wasm file are there (I am using a non hosted blazor wasm if that matters):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Simple template</title>
  </head>
  <body>

<script>
  loadWasm("dotnet.wasm")
    .then((wasm) => {
      console.log("dotnet.wasm is loaded");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("ouch", error);
    });
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

How can I display my wasm file without a running process? Is that even possible?

Comment: try dotnet-serve global tool

Comment: I researched a bit about the dotnet-serve tool but I do not understand how this can help. Is it generally possible to load web assemblies from the hard drive without server?

Comment: I missed the bit about "without running a process" - no the files need to be served by something.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an webassembly or blazor related question but Cross-Origin Resource Sharing related. Files even when they are from the same origin are seen as different origin by default in chrome. To disable that start chrome  with **--allow-file-access-from-files** from command line. In Firefox you could set **security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy** to flase to have the problem solved.